# C# Error en procedimiento para guardar imagen de PictureBox en base de datos

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2019, .netframework

Cordial saludo para todas las personas que están leyendo.

Tengo un proyecto **C# .NET Framework 4.7.2 Aplicación de Windows Form/Visual Studio 2019** y estoy usando MariaDB como DB de prueba.

El asunto es que para tratar de convertir la imagen de un PictureBox en un arreglo de bytes para que pueda ser almacenado en una tabla de base de datos con columna de tipo **Blob/LongBlob/VarBinary** tengo el siguiente procedimiento:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using MySqlConnector;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace LexSisCoVe
{
    class CRUD
    {
        private MySqlConnection Conectar = new MySqlConnection(@"Server=127.0.0.1; Port=3306; Database=test; Uid=root; Pwd=0123456789;");
        
        public void WorkImgs(String SQL, PictureBox Imagen)
        {
            MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream();
            Imagen.Image.Save(MS, Imagen.Image.RawFormat);
            byte[] Imagenes = MS.GetBuffer();
            MySqlCommand CMD = new MySqlCommand(SQL, Conectar);
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagen", Imagenes);
            try
            {
                Conectar.Open();
                CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Conectar.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                Conectar.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Siempre que intento usar este procedimiento, me salta erro en la linea:

```
Imagen.Image.Save(MS, Imagen.Image.RawFormat);
```

He buscado posibles soluciones y lo cambie de esta manera:

```
byte[] Imagenes = null;
using (MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream())
{
    Imagen.Image.Save(MS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    Imagenes = MS.ToArray();
}
```

Ya realizé exactamente lo mismo anteriormente, pero con **lenguaje VB .NET**, en dicha momento si logró realizar el guardado en la base de datos. El procedimiento era:

```
Imports MySqlConnector
Imports System.IO

Module CRUD
    Private Cadena As String = "Server=127.0.0.1; Port=3306; Database=test; Uid=root; Pwd=0123456789;"
    Private Conectar As New MySqlConnection(Cadena)
    
    Sub WorkImgs(ByVal SQL As String, ByVal Imagen As PictureBox)
        Dim MS As New MemoryStream
        Imagen.Image.Save(MS, Imagen.Image.RawFormat)
        Dim Imagenes() As Byte = MS.GetBuffer
        Dim CMD As New MySqlCommand(SQL, Conectar)
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagen", Imagenes)
        Try
            Conectar.Open()
            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Conectar.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Conectar.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

Como ya podran imaginar, no he logrado resolver el problema. Espero y me puedan ayudar con mi predicamento.

Acá dejo una captura del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por su atención.

Comment: Y dd está la consulta SQL que usas para insertar la imagen

Comment: El problema es mucho mas atras.. en vb.net todo esta en un modulo... en C#, en una clase, el error es clarisimo (y esta duplicado en la pagina)... Nunca le pasaste un valor a Imagen, o si, pero en otra clase...;)... no tenes problemas ni con sql, ni con otra cosa (por ahora).

Comment: ah y por favor, los errores como texto!!!!

Comment: Si, era que el no recibia la imagen del picturebox que había seleccionado, gracias por la ayuda.